# How to store data according to priority in database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to store my category list in database with priority...like

```
cat_id   cat_name   cat_priority
---------------------------------
 1        Test1         1
 2        Test2         2
 3        Test3         3
 4        Test4         4
```

Now if i have to set `Test1`priority to 3..then there will be conflict on `Test3` Now again if i want to set `Test2` priority to `4` then how i can fetch data via php according to priority system..How it will work, and what i need to change in my table structure..

Comment: Easiest way is to UPDATE all rows with a new cat_priority. Make sure you don't modify cat_id though.

Comment: oohh..you mean to say if i have lot of data...then we need to execute num of queries............!!!!!!!

Comment: Yes. How does your UI look? It will have all categories correct? If you want to limit your queries, and your UI is drag and drop or something similar, you can just do swaps on the cat_priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you will want to change an item priority, you will have to re-assign priority for each of them. I assume you do not want duplicate priority.

```
//$category = ...

//get all categories
$categories = $this->db->order_by('cat_priority')->select('cat_id, cat_priority')->get();

$cat_to_change = $category['cat_id'];
$new_priority = 2;
$i_priority = 0;
$new_categories = array();

foreach($categories->result_array() as $row)
{
    //this is the category we want to change, so change it
    if($row['cat_id'] == $cat_to_change)
    {
        $row['cat_priority'] = $new_priority;
    }
    else
    {
        //increment the priority
        $i_priority++;

        //the new priority is owned by another cat
        //so let it for the cat we want for him
        if($row['cat_priority'] == $new_priority)
            $i_priority++;

        $row['cat_priority'] = $i_priority;
    }

    $new_categories[] = $row;
}

//save
$this->db->update_batch('categories', $new_categories, 'cat_id');
```

Didn't test it. Hope it help.